# Representation of automorphism group of a curve acting on points of finite order in the Jacobian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-curves, automorphism-groups

Let $C$ be a curve of large genus $g > 1$ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$, and let $G = \textrm{Aut}(C)$ be its automorphism group. Is there a general way to compute the representation on $JC[p] \cong \mathbb{F}_p^{2g}$ or is this considered a hard problem? I'm interested in the case $p=2$ and I want to understand the answer for all plane quartic curves.

Comment: The group $JC[p]$ is canonically isomorphic to $H^1(C, \mathbb{Z}/p)$. The action of $G$ on this group is just the reduction mod. $p$ of the action on $H^1(C, \mathbb{Z})$ — and yes, there is a general way to compute it, using the Lefschetz fixed point formula.

Comment: By the way, the automorphism group of a general plane quartic curve is trivial, so the answer is rather easy in this case...

Comment: @abx what about the case when $p$ divides $|G|$? For $p = 2$ and $G = C_2$ acting by $x \mapsto -x$ on $C: x^4 + y^4+z^4 +a(x^2y^2 + z^2x^2 + y^2z^2)$, there are 4 fixed points generically in $a$, and Lefschetz says $-2 = tr(G | H^1(C,\mathbb{Z}))$. This would imply that $|H^1(C,\mathbb{Z})^G| = 4$, but calculations imply that $|JC[2]^G| = 8$. I don't see how this can happen when reducing mod $2$, since the integral indecomposable $C_2$ reps are either the identity, the sign or swapping a basis of a $2D$ vector space.

Comment: The sign representation becomes trivial when reducing mod. 2.

Comment: @abx Ah sorry I made a mistake, and in fact $|JC[2]^G|=16$. So there must be two swaps, one sign and one identity in the representation. Thanks!

Comment: @abx Lefschetz only provides a partial answer to the question. You can work out the complex representation but this can correspond to multiple (non-isomorphic) integral representations, which you need when reducing mod $p$.